# Google IAP Payment System

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I am completely new to the Google Play store. I was incorporating the Google Payment system into my app and I was wondering where can I get any info on which users have make an in-app purchase in my app? Will there be like an invoice number provided to me?

Answer (score 0):

When the checkout process is complete, Google Play sends your application the purchase details, such as the order number, the order date and time, and the price paid.

In-app and paid app orders are available both on your Google Play Developer Console (In-App Products section): https://play.google.com/apps/publish and on your Google Wallet Merchant Center's Orders page: https://wallet.google.com/merchant/. For more information about an order, click an individual order.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html